# Do I need two different PartnerLinks for two different calls to the same Web Service in BPEL?

Tags: bpel

If I want to make two parallel calls (in one flow activity) to the same web service in `BPEL`, do I need to create two different `PartnerLinks` or can I use the same one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke the same `partnerLink` multiple times in parallel in the same `flow`. You do not need to define a new one.

If you expect a result from the invocation, you need different `outputVariables`, however. If you write to the same `variable` in parallel, you will have race conditions just like in any other programming language.

Comment: Thanks @joergl, simple answer for a simple question. I already had the multiple variables in mind.

Comment: I am having a similar case but with the two parallel invocation to an asynchronous BPEL process (AsynchProcess) but I am receiving an axis2ns2:conflictingReceive fault. I am using two correlation sets one to correlate to the (Caller) BPEL process instance and one to correlate to the flow path. Do you have any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: @user1925930: A `conflictingReceive` fault is to be thrown if two recieves for the same partnerLink, operation, and correlationSet are activated. Are you sure you use different correlation sets? Try using different operations, this should normally work.

Comment: @joergl:I use the same PL, operation and correlationSets but the property of one of the correlationSets has different values in both cases. I understood that the msg is matched with the correlationSet property value, Am I wrong? I can't use different operations, it's a receive for callback which uses the same operation "onResult" of the asynch process on both paths of the flow. I tried also to use different local partner links for each path but I receive a TimeoutException. I added a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804135/bpel-conflicting-receive) with links to files.

Comment: ok the problem has been solved .. the solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804135/bpel-conflicting-receive) Thanks @joergl