# BPEL conflicting Receive

Tags: bpel, apache-ode

I have a scenario where a BPEL process with a parallel flow is calling an asynchronous process in parallel and waits for their callbacks. I added two correlation sets one to correlate to the calling BPEL process instance and one to correlate to the Receive in which flow path. But I am receiving a conflictingReceive fault response. And the error:

```
ERROR [PICK] org.apache.ode.bpel.common.FaultException: {Selector plinkInstnace=    {PartnerLinkInstance partnerLinkDecl=OPartnerLink#41,scopeInstanceId=9601},ckeySet=[{CorrelationKey setId=AsynchCorr, values=[hello]}, {CorrelationKey setId=FlowCorr, values=[flow 2:]}],opName=onResult,oneWay=yes,mexId=<null>,idx=0,route=one}
```

I am using Apache ODE with Tomcat. Can you help me find a solution for this problem, it is driving me mad!! I can send you sample projects if you can help.

Comment: I tried to use local Partner links for each scope in the two parallel flows, but I receive a TimeoutException waiting for callback

Comment: Please upload your .bpel and .wsdl file to gist and post the url here.

Comment: Caller Process BPEL [CallerProcess.bpel](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/6575881) and Caller Process WSDL [CallerProcessArtifacts.wsdl](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/6575910).... Asynchronous Process WSDL [AsynchProcessArtifacts.wsdl](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/6575935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I thought the msg is matched with the correlationSet property value .. I have defined another correlationSet with the same flow_property .. I updated the files in the comment above with the true solution. [CallerProcess.bpel](https://gist.github.com/faridasabry/6575881)